# Multiple source ans sink in max floq and min cut

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

I have been stuck in this problem...
Suppose we have a flow network with more than one source and sink nodes.
I have to Provide an example from yourself and explain how you can calculate its max-flow/min-cut.
And also have to find the min-cut of your example network

Yes we can solve the network by using dummy source and sink but how it exactly works that i am not able to understand...

Comment: this question belongs in https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a theory problem, so it may be better for cs.stackexchange... But what you said is correct - you add a new source and sink. the new source s* will have a directed edge to all of the sources in the original graph, and the capacity of edge (s*,s) for each source s can be set to infinity (of course, the flow out of s is constrained by its outward edges, so this does not change the amount of flow we are able to get from s).
Similarly, add a new sink t* with edges (t,t*) for all sinks t in the original graph. set the capacities to infinity, since the actual flow coming out of t is constrained by the amount of flow we could get to t in the original graph.